# Can I run Linux or even uCLinux on my STM32F407G-DISC1 Discovery board?

Tags: hardware, embedded, uclinux

This is my first question in this forum. I currently have a STM32F407G-DISC1 board. I wanted to install uCLinux on the board. But then I checked this website https://elinux.org/STM32 which seems to imply that my board can't run uCLinux (as of what I inferred). But I am not sure. Can I run uCLinux on my board?

Answer (score 1):

Your board has 192-Kbyte RAM and probably no possibility to add external RAM, so this is not enough to run uClinux.

If you want to run uClinux, make sure to take a µC with external RAM controller and a board with enough RAM populated.